# Cs50 plurality problem - Does not work in only 1 check

Tags: c, cs50

I made my code for the problem set 3 "plurality". When I check it, all answers are green, but there's only a problem with the "bob" answer
Here's the code, I include only the part with the function I implemented.
It's about a voting. In this function (after counting the votes for each candidate) you need to check who got the most votes and print the names. The function should take into consideration multiple winners. when I check the answer with the program given by cs50 all answers are red, only one answer marked as Bob but it doesn't explain what's the problem (in the previous problem set it did)

```
// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // Compare votes to select to biggest
    for (int i = 0; i < (candidate_count -1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (candidate_count - 2); j++)
        {
            // swap bigger number and name to last index
            if (candidates[i].votes > candidates[candidate_count - 1].votes)
            {
                candidates[candidate_count - 1].votes = candidates[i].votes;
                candidates[candidate_count - 1].name = candidates[i].name;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print every candidates that have same votes as votes of last index
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == candidates[candidate_count - 1].votes)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Please explain what the "plurality problem" is in the question.

Comment: You're not swapping anything. You're copying one element to the other, but not copying the other way.

Comment: Please also explain what is the "bob" answer?

Comment: Added more info on problem and answer Bob

Comment: @Barmar that was a stupid mistake. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: If you're sorting, use a sorting function. If you're just looking for the maximum you don't need to nest that loop, you can just scan once and record the max, then scan through on the second pass to filter and print.